# Grails 2 - Cannot create spring security domain object

Tags: spring, postgresql, grails, grails-2.0

I have installed the spring security app from th grails plugin page after running `grails s2-quickstart com.testApplication.secureApplication User Role` to autogenerate the domain object I did `grails run-app` and got this exception:

```
|Loading Grails 2.3.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
Precompiling AST Transformations ...
src C:\Users\GrailsWorkspace\testApplication\target\work\plugins\postgresql-extensions-0.6.1 C:\Users\GrailsWorkspace\testApplication\target\classes
Done precompiling AST Transformations!
..
|Compiling 3 source files
...................................................
|Running Grails application
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
Error |
2013-12-15 15:42:45,635 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: create table user (id int8 not null, version int8 not null, account_expired bool not null, account_locked bool not null, enabled bool not null, "password" varchar(255) not null, password_expired bool not null, username varchar(255) not null unique, primary key (id))
Error |
2013-12-15 15:42:45,638 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - ERROR: syntax error at "user"
  Position: 14
Error |
2013-12-15 15:42:45,688 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Unsuccessful: alter table user_role add constraint FK143BF46A1E03E05D foreign key (user_id) references user
Error |
2013-12-15 15:42:45,688 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - ERROR: syntax error at "user"
  Position: 90
|Server running.
```

The thing is my database is correctly configured, because I get the table `role` and `user_role`. However user does not get generate in my `postgresql db`. My implementation of my autogenerated `user domain object` looks like that:

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static transients = ['springSecurityService']

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

'user' is a reserved name in Postgres. You can avoid this by setting up a mapping in your domain class and use an alternate name.

```
 static mapping = { table 'myusers' }
```

This way your domain class remains the same. You could also escape the name similar to the way you have done with 'password'.

Comment: Would have never of thought of `user` being a keyword, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the user domain, add the following mapping configuration to keep the domain/table name `user` similar to the way `password` column is skipped.

```
static mapping = {
    table '`user`'
    password column: '`password`'
}
```

A blog post that explains the problem and the solution can be found [here](https://orkus.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/error-postresql-and-spring-secure-core/)

Comment: Tried this solution. It got past the first issue, but then it generates a new problem with the sequence naming: spi.SqlExceptionHelper ERROR: relation "seq_"user"" does not exist
I think it's better to avoid a table named 'user' in postgres.

Comment: @EdJ I didnot use any sequence naming and I didn't see this issue. As you said, if you can avoid a table named 'user', that is good but I like to keep this name.